# grep fails in upstart script

Tags: shell, script, escaping, upstart

I have an upstart configuration for a service which needs to check the existance of a process on it's startup. This sounds fairly easy but I'm already trying for 3 hours to get this thing solved and I'm lost. The problem seems to be that some grep statements lead to an exit of the script within upstart, leading to a failure in starting the service. But upstart doesn't log anything, it just exits the script and is gone.

Following are some example lines which trigger the problem: The first echo and the output of it's grep are logged, the second echo is logged, but not the output of it's grep. After the second echo upstart just exits the script and stops. The problem is adding the -v option or something other like using regexp classes like [[:digit:]]. It seems like I need to escape some characters but I simply don't know how. A simple -v or something like that doesn't work.

```
script
  echo grep
  ps ax | grep "postgres: wal writer process" | grep "grep"
  echo grep2
  ps ax | grep "postgres: wal writer process" | grep -v "grep"
end script
```

Does anyone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [the manual](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#develop-scripts-using-bin-sh), all scripts run with `sh -e`.  That means any unhandled command failure will terminate the script with an error.  If you have code which might return failure, you would code it like

```
command || true
```

or wrap it in a conditional or something.

By the by, your code is better written as

```
ps ax | grep "[p]ostgres: wal writer process"
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375711/more-elegant-ps-aux-grep-v-grep

So in summary, you would probably be looking for something like

```
if ps aux | grep '[p]ostgres: wal writer process'
then
    : already running
else
    : start it up
fi
```

Now that `grep` is run as part of a conditional, a failure is no longer considered unhandled (even if you don't have an `else` clause!) and so it will run safely under `set -e`.

Comment: Your statement doesn't work either, but now I think I understand the reason: The statement is supposed to fail if it doesn't find any matching lines which is a totally valid case. After the grep statements I have an if which checks the error code of the last statement, but because of an error code of 1 if the mathing line is not found and "sh -e" the if is never reached. There's nothing wrong with escape characters or else.

Comment: You should fix `grep foo bar; if [ $? = 0 ]; then ...` to the simpler, more robust, and more idiomatic `if grep foo bar; then ...`

Comment: I couldn't get something like `if [ ps ax | grep "postgres: wal writer process" | grep -v "grep" ]` or `if [ ps ax | grep "[p]ostgres: wal writer process" ]` even without [] form the if and escaped | or [p] to work.

Comment: Maybe see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586213/encounter-unary-operator-expected-in-bash-script/10586252#10586252

Comment: Or, to wit, `if ps aux | grep "[p]ostgres: wal writer process"; then ...` and notice in particular the absence of square brackets around the commands.

Comment: You are right, the [] were the problem. I tried without those before, but maybe it didn't work because my upstart config uses a symbolic link and didn't get refreshed after my changes. Now it works. Thanks a lot!